# I don't know how to show data in a datagridview by selecting a radio button option (Full Time or Part Time)

Tags: vb.net

I need to display the appropriate information in a datagridview using two radio buttons, a PartTimeRadioButton and FullTimeRadioButton. When someone selects the radio button it will show only those who are full time or only those who are part time. I don't have a clue how to even start this. I know how to display all of them by:

SalesDataGridView.DataSource = aCustomers.Items

the aCustomers comes from a Customers Class but was renamed in that form to aCustomers. I have attached a screen shot of the design of this project. I also have to have this done by 11:59 PM and have no idea how to do it.

The customers class code is:

```
Public Class Customers

'create a object variable (tableadapter)
'this will be used to creat instances of this class in the form

Private adapter As New CompanyDataSetTableAdapters.SalesStaffTableAdapter

'property to return a table using the GetData method
Public ReadOnly Property Items() As DataTable
    Get
        Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData
        table.DefaultView.Sort = "First_Name"
        Return table
    End Get
End Property

'create a function to filter the customers by custid
Public Function GetByCustomerId(custid As Short) As DataTable
    Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData 'entire table
    'filter to get desired row(s)
    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = " ID = " & custid
    Return table

End Function

End Class
```

The Display windows form with the datagridview and radio buttons code is:

```
' For the datagridview, display only first name, last name, fulltime, hiredate and salary
' If you do not want to display the column, use the visible property.
' For example, SalesDataGridView.Columns(0).Visible = false

' To accumulate the total salary, you can use the cells in the datagridview
' For example, id is in cells(0).

Public Class frmDisplay
Private aCustomers As New Customers
Private formLoading As Boolean = True

Private Sub radFT_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


End Sub

Private Sub radPT_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    SalesDataGridView.DataSource = aCustomers.Items
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: You might want to start narrow this down to more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out how to display fulltime customers only.
2. Figure out how to display parttime customers only. This will be easy after step 1.
3. When the radio button changes, reload the the appropriate data (what you did in step 1 and 2). You can handle this in the checkedchanged event.